# DispatchQueue.main and thread safety

Tags: swiftui, thread-safety, state

Consider the following toy example

```
import SwiftUI

struct WeirdExample: View {
    @State private var greetings = ["Hello", "Bye"]
    @State private var count = 0
    @State private var greetingIndex = 0
    
    func modifyCount() {
        count = (count + 1) % 100
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(150) , execute: modifyCount)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(greetings[greetingIndex])
            Spacer()
            Button("Change (maybe)"){
                if count % 2 == 0 {
                    greetingIndex = (greetingIndex + 1) % 2
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear(){modifyCount()}
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, everything in the example is running on the UI thread. However, I'm concerned by the fact that assigning to the *count* variable is not atomic. Is it conceivable to have a situation in which pressing the button catches that variable in a weird, undefined state? In other words, is an item dispatched to the main queue guaranteed to run uninterrupted until completion? Of course, being a serial queue guarantees that a job on the queue won't begin executing until the previous ones are finished running, but since there is a distinction between main thread and main queue, I wonder if there is reason for concern about this, or somehow the fact that everything is running on the main thread obviates any problems. Thanks.

Comment: Look into `async await` `@MainActor` and `actor`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I am aware of those, and I can also think of alternatives, but my question is whether there is actually a problem in the situation as stated.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you: are you saying that there is indeed a problem? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but since there is a distinction between main thread and main queue.

The main queue is guaranteed to run on the main thread. It is also where the main RunLoop is, where `@MainActor` things run, and where the main OperationQueue runs, and all of these things are serialized. While there is a difference between threads and queues (and you're wise to keep that in mind), "main" is the one case where all of the relevant things are equivalent. No, there is no race condition here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you happen to have a reference where I can learn more about this?

Comment: If you want to understand these things deeply, I highly recommend the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1). Yes, it is very old, and hasn't been updated since before Swift was first released, but it's still the foundational text for understanding GCD, and understanding GCD in an ObjC context is often subtly assumed by much of the Swift documentation.